# Как работают пользовательские свойства функции?

Tags: javascript

Помогите понять, как работает данный код:

```js
function makeCounter() {

  function counter() {
    return counter.count++;
  };

  counter.count = 0;

  return counter;  
}

let counter = makeCounter(); 
console.log( counter() );
console.log( counter() );
```

Код взят [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-object#polzovatelskie-svoystva). Сначала я подумал, что, когда **makeCounter()** присваивается **let counter**, то в лексическом окружении **let counter** хранится функция **counter()** и свойство **counter.count = 0**, но когда я попытался изменить название **counter()**, то получил ошибку. Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом коде считается количество вызовов функции counter() и выводится сама функция.

```
function makeCounter() {   //Объявляется функция в которой что-то происходит, а именно вызов функции counter() и затем вывод переменной counter

  function counter() {   //Объявляется функция в которой что-то происходит, а именно:
    return counter.count++; // К значению counter.count прибавляется единица при каждом вызове функции counter()
  };

  counter.count = 0;  // От какого числа вести отсчёт.

  return counter;    // Возвращает нам полученное значение. которое мы присвоим. В данном случае ему потом присваивается текст функции let counter = makeCounter()
}

let counter = makeCounter(); // Присвоение переменной counter функции counter() как значение, а не как выполнении функции.
console.log( counter() ); // Вывод данных функции counter()
console.log( counter() ); // Вывод данных функции counter()
```

Данная функция эквивалента такому решению, но без вывода самой функции.

```
counter.count = 0;
function counter() {
return counter.count++;
};


console.log( counter() );
console.log( counter() );
```

Но во втором случае Вы переменную counter.count выводите за пределы функции, где сначала её объявляете.

Answer (score 0):

Подробно вам уже описали, а если по простому, то функция возвращает вложенную функцию, которая считает количество вызовов функции. А то, что let counter назвали похоже на вложенную функцию - это просто недоработка автора кода.

```js
function makeCounter() {

  function counter() {
    return counter.count++;
  };

  counter.count = 0;

  return counter;  
}

let counter = makeCounter(); 
console.log(counter); // сама вложенная функция
console.log(counter()); // 0
console.log(counter()); // 1
```