# Остановить таймер, когда значение переменной станет равно 10

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Как я могу остановить таймер с помощью `clearInterval()`, когда счётчик станет равен `10`?

```
function counter() {
    counter.count = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        counter.count++;
        console.log(counter.count);
    }, 1000);
    return counter.count

}

counter();
```

Comment: Что за глупый код? Название функции совпадает с названием объекта... можно сто раз запутаться, что есть counter

Comment: Внешнего объекта нет на самом деле. Функция сама по себе и есть объект, которая имеет свойства name, length... тут я еще ей добавляю и свойство counter.

Comment: Здесь легко можно обойтись локальной переменной `count`. Не стоит вводить людей в заблуждение

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Это будет неравнозначная замена.

Comment: Почти равнозначная. Но я не вижу никакого проку от того, что counter.count будет доступен извне. Тем более, что это кастыльное решение, и может обернуться кучей проблем, аналогичных тем, к каким приводят использование глобальный переменных, да еще и в асинхронных вычислениях.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, Какой смысл в твоих комментариях, что именно ты предлагаешь? (относительно вопроса)

Comment: @yar85 заменить переменную counter.count на лоокальную count

Comment: @yar85 смотри, например, этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1065255/176536 там также указывается на недоработку синтаксиса, по вопросу с функцией с таким же названием и такой же проблемой.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, Пожалуйста, посмотри на комментарий выше, где уже сказано что такая замена будет неравнозначной. По факту, твое предложение игнорирует суть вопроса, и выдвинуто без знания решаемой задачи. Если автор вопроса тебя услышал, то не проявил интереса - и этого вроде достаточно, чтобы остановить поток неконструктивной критики кода в комментариях. Тем более он новый участник... поэтому, будь добр, держи себя в руках. Если хочешь рассказать о проблемах кода подробно - напиши ответ, это будет полезно всем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием [деструктуризации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) аргумента функции:

```js
function counter({ start=0, end, step=1, delay=1000 } = {}) {
  counter.count = start - step; 
  const interval = setInterval(function () {
    if ((counter.count += step) >= end)
      clearInterval(interval);
    console.log(counter.count);
  }, delay);
  return interval; 
}

counter({ start: 0, end: 10 });
```

Если необходимо занести параметры в свойства объекта функции, это можно сделать выражением

```
Object.assign(counter, { start, end, step, delay });
```

, и тогда лучше будет внутри функции обращаться именно к свойствам (конкретно `end` и `step`, влияют на выполнение - доступ к ним снаружи может быть удобен).

---

Возвращать лучше не начальное значение, а ID таймера (значение переменной `interval`), для возможности его остановить досрочно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сейчас нужно вникнуть во все это

Comment: @faceVB, Пожалуйста ;) Если есть уточняющие вопросы по каким-то конкретным деталям ответа - спрашивай, попробую объяснить

Answer (score 2):

```js
function counter() {
  counter.count = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter.count++;
    console.log(counter.count);
    if (counter.count >= 10) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log("stopped");
    }
  }, 1000);
  return counter.count
}

counter();
```

Comment: Я даже вопрос не успел открыть, а тут всё уже готово ) Igor молодец.

Comment: То есть просто переменную добавить нужно было?)

Comment: @faceVB да, и `clearInterval`

Comment: Да clearInterval() я пихал везде. А по имени функции нельзя было остановить, типа clearInterval(counter)?

Comment: @faceVB Хм, в `clearInterval` передается то, что было возвращено вызовом `setInterval`. Функция `counter` здесь не к месту.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо..!

Comment: @faceVB Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.